# Which kernel function called on timer_settime() and timer handler implemented in User space?

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, posix

I have a multi-threaded program where I have created a timer in main thread using `timer_create()` function. Then I set timer using `timer_settime()` function. When the timer expired after the timer duration it called the registered timer handler function.

Here is my code snippet:

```
#define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
#define SIG SIGRTMIN
int ret;
timer_t timerid;
struct sigevent sev;
struct itimerspec its;

sigset_t mask;
struct sigaction sa;


static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{

}

void *threadA(void *data_)
{

      while(1)
      {

        its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = DELAY1;
        its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

        ret = timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL);
        if ( ret < 0 )
            perror("timer_settime");
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
      sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
      sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
      err = sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL);
      if (0 != err) {
           printf("sigaction failed\n"); }

      sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
      sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
      sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
      ret = timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid);
      if ( ret < 0 )
           perror("timer_create");

}
```

I want to know which are functions are called in kernel space , when I call `timer_create()`, `timer_settime()` function inside my C program.

Also, which kernel function is responsible to call timer handler when timer expires ?

Inside *`include/linux/posix-clock.h`* file, I found following definitions, but no definition of those functions.

```
/**
 * struct posix_clock_operations - functional interface to the clock
 * @timer_create:   Create a new timer

 * @timer_settime: Set a timer's initial expiration and interval
 */     

struct posix_clock_operations {
    struct module *owner;

    int  (*timer_create) (struct posix_clock *pc, struct k_itimer *kit);



    int  (*timer_settime)(struct posix_clock *pc,
                          struct k_itimer *kit, int flags,
                          struct itimerspec *tsp, struct
                          timerspec *old);
```

Answer (score 0):

`strace` your program and you will see which syscalls are used.

In some cases this may depend on your libc, as kernel often offers multiple ways to achieve something.

Answer (score 0):

You can search kernel/time/posix-timers.c

```
 530 SYSCALL_DEFINE3(timer_create, const clockid_t, which_clock,
 531         struct sigevent __user *, timer_event_spec,
 532         timer_t __user *, created_timer_id)
```

which call

```
do_timer_create
```